# Не скролится по ссылке в лендинге

Tags: html, css

Сделал менюшку в шапке, создал обычные ссылки которые ссылаются к id блоку, но при нажатии скролл не срабатывает и оно просто листается в самый верх лендинга, в чем может быть причина, помогите пожалуйста разобраться.

Ленд - http://asvpage.mcdir.ru/13cv/

Comment: У вас переход блочится в файле script.min.js

Comment: @E_K 7 уже перерыл весь файл, как это исправить можно ?

Comment: Что у вас за скрипты в этом файле?

Comment: как я понял там скрипт который отвечает за переходы между инф на лендинге, где в блоке есть выбор между несколькими вариантами, например 1 очередь, 2 очередь, вот за это

Comment: я этот ленд скачивал и редактировал некоторые элементы, сейчас попробую показать что в том файле

Comment: Да я вижу что там

Comment: а как это можно исправить ? это возможно ?

Comment: Как на меня самый простой вариант, это убрать этот файл. Посмотреть, где и что сломалось, и самому сделать нормально так как надо.

Answer (score 3):

Вот рабочий вариант

```js
$('ul li').on('click',function(){
  var liClass = $(this).attr('class');
  var slidePos = $('.slide.s'+liClass).offset().top;
  $(window).scrollTop(slidePos);
});
```

```css
body {margin: 0;}
ul {width: 50px; padding: 5px 0; background: #fff; position: fixed; right: 5px; top: 5px; margin: 0;}
li {display: block; width: 100%; background: #ccc; margin-bottom: 5px; text-align: center; cursor: pointer;}
.slide {width: 100%; height: 200px;}
.slide.s1 {background: red;}
.slide.s2 {background: blue;}
.slide.s3 {background: yellow;}
.slide.s4 {background: green;}
.slide.s5 {background: gray;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="1">1</li>
  <li class="2">2</li>
  <li class="3">3</li>
  <li class="4">4</li>
  <li class="5">5</li>
</ul>

<div class="slide s1">1</div>
<div class="slide s2">2</div>
<div class="slide s3">3</div>
<div class="slide s4">4</div>
<div class="slide s5">5</div>
```